# Fourier transform involving completion of square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integral-transforms

> Show that the Fourier transform of 
>   $$f(x) = k e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$
>   is 
>   $$F( \lambda) = \frac{k}{\sigma}e^{\frac{-\sigma^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$$

By definition of the Fourier transform:

$$F(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x)e^{-i\lambda x}dx$$

I have a problem with completing the square. Applying the procedure mechanically brings me nowhere.
Yet, I find the solution to lack clarity.

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} - i\lambda x
&= -\frac{1}{2}\biggl[\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2} + 2i\lambda x\biggr] \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\biggl[\biggl(\frac{x}{\sigma} + i\lambda \sigma\biggr)^2 - (i\lambda\sigma)^2\biggr] \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\biggl(\frac{x}{\sigma} + i\lambda\sigma\biggr)^2 - \frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2}
\end{align}$$

Would someone be kind to expound on the 'tricks' used in the completing the square?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here - in what sense is the procedure unclear? Completing the square _is_ a very formulaic procedure, after all.

Comment: @DavidZ Sure it is. But why wouldn't it suffice to take the square of the half of the second term ($$i \lambda x$$?).
The first inequality is a result of the manipulating the first equation. Why?
It looks unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: Ah, see, if that's what's confusing you, edit the question to ask about that, and it will be much better. (Or better yet, you might try taking the square of half the second term to see what happens, and then see where you run into trouble after that.)